# Problem Install R on OS 10.14

Tags: rlink

Using Mathematica 12.1.0.0 on Mac OS 10.14

Attemping to use my version of R

Tried using:

```
Needs["RLink`"]
JLink`UninstallJava[]
InstallR["RVersion" -> "3.61", 
 "RHomeLocation" -> 
  "/Users/james2/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rtest/lib/R/library", 
 "NativeLibLocation" -> 
  "/Users/james2/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rtest/lib/R/library/rJava/jri"]
```

Received error message:
Failed to install R.  The following error was encountered:crash in low-lever RLink component or in R runtime

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing your directory structure, but I would guess that, first, you need `"RVersion" -> "3.6.1"` (you missed the dot between `6` and `1`, which could make it impossible for RLink to parse the version number), and second, you might want to point `"RHomeLocation" ` to just `"/Users/james2/opt/anaconda3/envs/Rtest/lib/R"`, without the last `library` subfolder. If this doesn't work, it might help to attach the screenshot of your folder structure for R.

Comment: It might also help to fire R shell for your R distribution, and execute `R.home()` there - that should give the path to set `"RHomeLocation"` to.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Helpful comments, it seems you know lots about RLink! Are there any good ways of plotting things with R in 12.1?

Comment: @user5601 I am the developer of RLink. Re: plotting - not easy in 12.1, but hopefully will improve in 12.2. I talked about this in my talk on the Wolfram University webinar yesterday, the recording of it should soon become available.